# How to extract column from pandas Dataframe to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe named `df` and I want to extract the `stud_name` column and `stud_grade` column and convert it to a pandas series named `StudentSeries`. the index is `stud_name`.

My attempt:

```
StudentSeries = pd.Series(df, index='stud_name')
```

Comment: Did you go through the user guide section title “Selection”?

Comment: Which user guide?

Comment: The one on the pandas website

Comment: Yes but i couldn't find any clue in their website

Comment: The first heading under the Selection User Guide explains how to select a column into a series

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and [pandas.Series.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
StudentSeries = pd.Series(df['stud_grade'].values, index=df['stud_name'].values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and extract the column:

```
StudentSeries = df.set_index('stud_name')['stud_grade']
```